# How do I check if a React component is expecting a prop?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to wrap a variety of components in a `Modal`, which will pass `closeModal` properties into any children which support it.

Currently I'm following [this post](https://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/) and using a JS property `closesModal` to signal that the parent should pass in the closer method, i.e.:

```
React.Children.map(
  this.props.children,
  child => (
    child.closesModal ?
      React.cloneElement(child, { closeModal: this.close }) :
      child
  )
)
```

Is this a fair way to go about accomplishing what I want, and is there a way to introspect a React component to see whether or not it expects a property?

Comment: You can check the using `propTypes `

Comment: Those docs say "Note: React.PropTypes is deprecated as of React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead". Do I really need to install a separate library to accomplish something this tiny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample example for same:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';  // for React version React >=v15.5 

class Greeting extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  // This indicates name should be passed as props from parent. 
  name: PropTypes.string.required
};
```

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Thanks, I can try this tomorrow, but are you sure? I am trying to only run the `React.cloneElement` piece if the component exists. Can I check that with `propTypes` after how you have defined it?